# How to implement Primary key OR unique key for user id in Sqlite for Android studio

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I'm new to Android Application Development. I am trying to Insert values in Database. My code is

```
 public void onClick(View view) 

{

            if(view==register)

            {
           if(user_id.getText().toString().trim().length()==0||
                        password.getText().toString().trim().length()==0||
                        email.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || contact.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
                {
                    showMessage("Error", "Please enter all values");
                    return;
                }

                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO customer VALUES('"+user_id.getText()+"','"+password.getText()+
                        "','"+email.getText()+"','"+contact.getText()+"');");
                showMessage("Success", "Record added"); // showMessage is Print function
                clearText();
            }
        }
```

As i inserted Duplicate user_id my application get closed. I want to display message dat User id is not available on duplicate entries. can i use try catch block ? or something else. Please suggest.

Comment: Yes, you can use it. Catch the exception that you get in the logcat and display the message.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.I want to display message to User. Not in Console. Can i ?

Comment: Yes. Use Toast for that.

Comment: Thank you Preak Sola. I'm trying to implement your suggestion. I will reply you here after implementation.

Comment: Thank you PrerakSola. Its Working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code below.

```
try{
      db.execSQL("INSERT INTO customer VALUES('"+user_id.getText()+"','"+password.getText()+
                                "','"+email.getText()+"','"+contact.getText()+"');");
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Register inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch(SQLException e)){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Register already exists in database!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Lucas

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark like this: i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png Thanks!